# How to handle properly body params in @post request when using data classed with generics

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I'm trying to create endpoint for a post request:

```
@Singleton
@Controller("/v1")
class Addr() {

    @Post("/setAddress")
    fun set(@Body body: RpcRequest<Address>) {
        println(body.params.newAddress)
    }
}
```

Data:

```
data class Address(val newAddress: String)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class RpcRequest<T>(
    val method: String,
    val params: T
)
```

But unfortunately, error occured:

`java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.project.location.data.Address`

Seems like Micronaut couldn't resolve my `Address` data class inside `RpcRequest` ?

Comment: "Seems like Micronaut couldn't resolve my Address data class inside RpcRequest ?" - I do not think that is the case.  If Micronaut couldn't resolve the class you wouldn't be able to get a class cast exception referencing the class.

Comment: Try annotating both classes with `@Introspected`